# Asset Pipeline Plugin - Grails equivalent to rails "include" functionality

Tags: angularjs, grails, asset-pipeline

I am looking for a way, using the Grails asset-pipeline plugin, to include a file into a bundle more than once. The reason for this being, I would like to create a wrap around particular sections of my code to implement 'use strict' in a modular way because of a bug with Safari and AngularJS.

Anyone know of a way to do this? I know that it is supposed to be like the Rails asset-pipeline, but it doesn't like "include".

Right now, the javascript file looks like this:

```
//= require ../beginWrap.js
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
//= require ../endWrap.js

angular.module('app', []);
```

I would like it use "include" like the Rails plugin it was designed from:

```
//= include ../beginWrap.js
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
//= include ../endWrap.js

angular.module('app', []);
```

It just doesn't seem to work like that. Anyone know why?

Comment: That question is not like mine. I was talking about the asset-pipeline includes and requires within javascript files, not gsp files. I edited my question to provide examples.

Comment: Sorry Peter I didn't really get time to focus on Q at hand. Deleted first comment and been trying find something similar and I couldn't find anything like this documented. You can exclude stuff from Config.groovy related to plugins http://www.davydotcom.com/blog/2014-02-25-faster-asset-compilation-with-grails-asset-pipeline .. There is also this https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/wiki/Why-asset-pipeline-over-grails-resources-plugin which has a segment about file dependencies - again does not really answer your question but delves deepr into assets.